# Using field alias in MSQuery does not work with DB2

Tags: db2, ms-query, ibm-data-studio

This query works in data studio, but fails to show alias in MS Query!
I have tried different types such as "",'',[] and even https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/298955

SELECT 'TRANIN'AS NAME, SUM(CASE WHEN  ALT3.TRANINDT BETWEEN 20150603 AND 20150601 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS CurrentMonth, SUM(CASE WHEN  ALT3.TRANINDT BETWEEN 20150501 AND 20150531 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS LastMonth 
FROM ALT3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS broke MS query a long time ago...

I've tried to get it to work right, but nothing worked.  I've pretty much given up.

Normally I just rename the column once the data is back in Excel.

But if you really want the name returned from MS query, this works:

```
WITH tbl AS (SELECT 'TRANIN'AS NAME
             , SUM(CASE WHEN ALT3.TRANINDT BETWEEN 20150603 AND 20150601 
                     THEN 1 else 0 END) AS CurrentMonth
             , SUM(CASE WHEN ALT3.TRANINDT BETWEEN 20150501 AND 20150531 
                     THEN 1 else 0 END) AS LastMonth 
             FROM ALT3)
SELECT * FROM TBL
```